# How to stop scanf with less arguments

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, stdin

I need to keep getting 3 values ​​(int, int, float) from the keyboard and only stop the loop when I enter 0.

The problem is that when I enter 0 and press [Enter it keeps waiting for the second and third value.

```
    int i, j; float v;
    while (scanf("%i %i %f", &i, &j, &v) == 3){
        Matrix* M = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
        M->line = i;
        M->column = j;
        M->info = v;
        printf("loop");
    }
```

I know that scanf returns an integer representing the number of successfully captured values, the question is: How to stop waiting for new inputs and return the number of already captured. (So i can exit the loop in this case.)

Comment: You'll have to `scanf("%d", &i)` separately from the other two and check its value before continuing to read the input, or decide that you are willing to type an end of file character to exit instead (that is `Control-D` instead of `0`).

Comment: Does it have to be `0`, or are you allowed to use `q` to quit?

Comment: Haxor Batista, what should happen is user input does not match either? (int, int , float) or 0

Answer (score 2):

I would consider just reading whole lines in the loop and then parsing that line using `sscanf` inside the loop. Return value 1 and the first value parsed as `0` would indicate your desired ending condition. When you had the complete line available, you could also present better error diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, would you please try:

```
    char line[BUFSIZ];

    while (fgets(line, BUFSIZ, stdin)) {
        if (strcmp(line, "0\n") == 0 || strcmp(line, "q\n") == 0)
            break;
        else {
            sscanf(line, "%i %i %f", &i, &j, &v);
            ...
        }
    }
```

Entering just `0` or `q` will exit the loop.

Comment: It worked, i did char *s = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char)); while(i!=0){fgets (s, 100, stdin); sscanf(s, "%d%d%f", &i, &j, &v); ... thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Reasonable modification.